# How to log and save file with date and timestamp in Python

Tags: python, csv, datetime, raspberry-pi

I am trying to log temperature from a DS18B20 sensor using Raspberry Pi 3 via Python code executed from shell.

I want to log temperature with timestamp and then save the file.

What I am doing presently is saving it to a filename entered in the code, but I want to log the file with date and timestamp in filename.

**Case 1 :** When I put a filename in the code, then I can append data to the same file over and over, but I can't start a new separate logging without editing the code.

```
#Writes data to file
def write_temp(temperature):
        with open("/home/pi/temp.csv", "a") as log:
                log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),str(temperature)))
```

Problem is that the file is always temp.csv and data gets appended each time.

**Case 2**: I tried to get filename from timestamp, but each second a new file is getting generated.

```
def write_temp(temperature):
        filename1 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        #filename1 = sys.argv[1]
        with open('%s.csv' % filename1, 'a') as log:
                log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),str(temperature)))
```

In the above case, I would rather like to have the filename set at the start of logging each time or at the end of logging. I would also like to save the name as Log-*DateTime* instead of just DateTime. I tried this by doing `('"Log-" + %s.csv' % filename1, 'a')` instead of `('%s.csv' % filename1, 'a')`, but that didn't work out.

**Ideal Case:** I want file name to be WORD-*DateTime*, where WORD is sent as an argument from the command line, as in below:

```
sudo python TTLogging.py WORD
```

Can you point out where I am going wrong? I can share the full code of my work if required since it is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Case 2**, every time `write_temp` is called, it is populating `filename1` with timestamp.

So consider,for example, you called it at `10:15:13 (hh:mm:ss)`, then `filename1` will be `10-15-13.csv`. When you will call it again at `10:15:14` then `filename1` will be `10-15-14.csv`.

That's why new file is getting created.

**Solution :** Take out `filename1` from `temp_write` and pass filename to that function as argument.

```
from datetime import *
import sys

def write_temp(temperature,file_name):

        print ("In write_temp function - "+file_name)

        with open(file_name, 'a') as log:
                log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),str(temperature)))


arg = sys.argv[1]
filename1 = str(arg) + "-" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")+".csv"
print ("File name is "+filename1)
write_temp(1,filename1)
```

**Output on console:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py LOG
File name is LOG-2016-09-27-11-03-16.csv
In write_temp function - LOG-2016-09-27-11-03-16.csv

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

**Output of LOG-TimeStamp.csv:**

```
2016-09-27 10:47:06,1
2016-09-27 10:47:06,3
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, what is the significance of write_temp(1) and write_temp(3)?

Comment: @Dr.Viper - Please check the updated code. I have just called the above function to test it

Comment: Ok, now that makes sense to me. Also, shouldn't the line ¬filename1 = str(arg) + "-" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")+".csv"¬ be file_name =

Comment: Not required. file_name is function argument where as filename1 is variable defined in main block. Both variables are in kind of different scope.

Comment: Then sorry for making the edit to your answer. I apologize. But how will the function write_temp know that it has to use filename1 for file_name? Genuine question. Not a CS fellow here, unfortunately. Sorry to bother.

Comment: So, when I am calling write_temp(1,filename1) I am passing 1 and filename1. In function write_temp temperature is populated with 1 and file_name is populated with filename1

Comment: So now function write_temp knows which file to write.

Comment: So for your understanding, add print (filename1) after filename1 = str(arg) + "-" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")+".csv"

Comment: Add print ("In function "+file_name) in write_temp after def write_temp(temperature,file_name):

Comment: @Dr.Viper - Check my updated code and output. I have printed filename from both place

Comment: I am getting list index out of range for the arg = sys.srgv[1] command

Comment: Are you executing script as - python TTLogging.py WORD ??

Comment: Nope. That was my mistake, also, next I found that I hadn't update write_temp(temperature) to write_temp(temperature,filename1). Now it works with filename1 as the argument for filename.

I have learned more in Python from the last 30 minutes with you than in my attempts at it in the last 2 weeks. You are a genius. Thanks a million. How do I give you 100000 rep points for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
with open('Log-%s.csv' % filename1, 'a') as log:
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tried, and the problem of getting a new file each second of logging remains. I am getting Log-date and time.csv, Log-date and time after 1s.csv, etc.....
I want to log to 1 file till the logging is stopped. even though a is there, it is not appending.